vite lit webcomponennts : export regular ts files apart from components ts files
I hope someone with experience in webcomponents could help on this.
Client having an application loading webcomponents js file using
<script type"application/javascript" src="path-to-webcomponents.js" />

consumer app happily loading webcomponents such as <login-btn> </login-btn> good.

Question: I would like to have have export "login js internally used
by this webcomponent" to consumer app, so I could use
login.isUserLoggedIn()

Is this even possible or not correct way to approach.
Any help appreciated.
